# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in SQLiteDatabase rawQuery()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqlcipher

I cannot get around this Exception. Am i missing something obvious?

**Stack Trace**

```
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1470
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=6
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:69)
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1420)
12-05 20:07:43.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4154):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1389)
```

---

**Query used**

Query= `SELECT column1,max(datetime(creation_timestamp)) FROM table_name where dfs_id=? GROUP BY column2`

(column1, column2, table_name etc are placeholders - not the actual names)

Argument passed = `"a08eff29ee6a71dd_1381146091100_0002"`

---

Note: I am using SQLCipher(A wrapper around SQLCipher), which should not be relevant to this exception.

Comment: is the name of your table `table`?

Comment: The SQL is invalid: `table` needs to be quoted in backticks if it's a table name, no expression between `AND` and `GROUP BY`. But those would likely cause some other exception. Please post the Java code where you do your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/src/net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteProgram.java#L69) that causes the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is the following.

```
/* package */ SQLiteProgram(SQLiteDatabase db, String sql) {
    mDatabase = db;
    mSql = sql.trim();
    db.acquireReference();
    db.addSQLiteClosable(this);
    this.nHandle = db.mNativeHandle;

    // only cache CRUD statements
    String prefixSql = mSql.substring(0, 6); // <<<< HERE
```

The only reason why you can get that exception is a `String` with less than 6 characters. (Your's is `length=0;` i.e. empty after the `trim()` a few lines above)

There is no indication where or how exactly you manage to put an empty string in there. It comes from a `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery` but that could have been called from other query methods. Look further down the stacktrace and look through your code where you are possibly passing an empty string to a query method.

---

Your query also seems to break the syntax of the where clause:
If there is an `AND` it would have to be

```
WHERE {condition} AND {another condition expected here} GROUP BY ...
```

You have either forgot to add another [expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) or you have an `AND` too much.

And `table` is a reserved keyword. To use those as names you'll have to quote them. [SQLite supports](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) quotation marks ("), backticks (`) and brackets ([]).

Comment: 'AND' was a typo. But yes, i found out the problem to be a empty String

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using `table` for the name of your table. `TABLE` is a command in SQL; it should not be used for table names. Since SQL is not case-sensitive `TABLE` is the same as `table`. Just change the name of your table to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The stack strace shows that you give an empty query string to the `rawQuery` function.